# PHP Docker write to stderr through file

Tags: php, docker, logging, stderr

Is it possible to redirect a plain text log file to stderr within a Docker container that is writable by PHP?

I have a PHP application that is writing to a file and we're trying to move it into a Docker container without changing any code. I've tried symlinking but this results in permissions errors.

Comment: what about docker volumes?

Comment: This could work and has been considered but we were hoping for a seamless solution that doesn't show anything within the host directories, but can be accessed via `docker logs`

Comment: https://serversforhackers.com/c/dckr-file-permissions. This might helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding this solution which uses a `fifopipe` to pipe the data into stdout.

```
# Allow `nobody` user to write to /dev/stderr
mkfifo -m 600 /tmp/logpipe
chown nobody:nobody /tmp/logpipe
cat <> /tmp/logpipe 1>&2 &
```

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6880#issuecomment-344114520

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what type of symlinking you tried but you should be able to do this with something like

> RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /path/to/your/text.log

In your Dockerfile (where the text.log path is the one inside the container).

Comment: Unfortunately symlinking didn't work. The Apache user threw permissions errors when using this solution.